# VSCode pipenv already activated issue

Tags: visual-studio-code, pipenv

I worked python project with `pipenv` and edit my code with VSCode.

When I activate pipenv in my terminal, it works perfectly like this.

[image]

But When I activate in VSCode terminal, it throws error -> `already activated`

[image]

Of course I deactivate pipenv at my terminal before activate in vscode terminal.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Python extension activated in VSC, familiarize yourself with [this pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/pull/888). They added support for `pipenv`, that's why the shell is active there already.